# Перерисовка холста в - не работает invalidate()

Tags: java, android

Делаю несложную игру, пытаюсь запрограммировать `D-Pad`, чтобы он нормально работал. Сама кнопка нажимается, и при нажатии на неё в лог выводится, что кнопка нажата, но перерисовки холста не происходит. В документации сказано что `invalidate()` делает так, что в будущем будет вызван `onDraw()`. Но вызова метода `onDraw()` не происходит. Почему?

Код (если нужен будет какой то еще код, напишите в комментариях, добавлю):

Холст:

```
public class DrawSurface extends View {
    private final ImageManager im = new ImageManager(getResources());
    private final Terrain terrain = new Terrain(128);
    private int width, height;
    private ImmovableSprite buttonDown, buttonUp, buttonLeft, buttonRight;
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final Unit unit = new Unit("UNIT", 100, 10, 10, 100, "Sword", terrain.getSpawnPoint()[0], terrain.getSpawnPoint()[1]);

    public DrawSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);

        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        fillCanvas(canvas, Color.BLACK);
        drawTerrain(canvas);
        drawButtons(canvas);
    }

    private void drawButtons(Canvas canvas) {
        if (buttonDown == null) buttonDown = new ImmovableSprite(width, height, width / 9 * 2, (int) (getTerrainDrawData()[1] + width / 9 * (getTerrainDrawData()[2] - 1.5)), im, im.buttonDown);
        if (buttonUp == null) buttonUp = new ImmovableSprite(width, height, width / 9 * 2, (int) (getTerrainDrawData()[1] + width / 9 * (getTerrainDrawData()[2] - 3.5)), im, im.buttonUp);
        if (buttonRight == null) buttonRight = new ImmovableSprite(width, height, width / 9 * 3, (int) (getTerrainDrawData()[1] + width / 9 * (getTerrainDrawData()[2] - 2.5)), im, im.buttonRight);
        if (buttonLeft == null) buttonLeft = new ImmovableSprite(width, height, width / 9, (int) (getTerrainDrawData()[1] + width / 9 * (getTerrainDrawData()[2] - 2.5)), im, im.buttonLeft);
        buttonDown.draw(canvas);
        buttonUp.draw(canvas);
        buttonRight.draw(canvas);
        buttonLeft.draw(canvas);
    }

    private void drawTerrain(Canvas canvas) {
        int drawX = getTerrainDrawData()[0];
        int drawY = getTerrainDrawData()[1];
        for (int x = unit.getX() - 4; x <= unit.getX() + 4; x++) {
            for (int y = unit.getY() - (int) Math.floor(getTerrainDrawData()[2] / 2);
                y <= unit.getY() + (int) Math.floor(getTerrainDrawData()[2] / 2); y++) {
                Bitmap img = null;
                switch (terrain.getBlock(x, y).toString()) {
                    case "+":
                        img = im.wall;
                        break;
                    case " ":
                        img = im.floor;
                        break;
                    case "o":
                        img = im.chest;
                        new ImmovableSprite(width, height, drawX, drawY, im, im.floor).draw(canvas);
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        img = im.spawn;
                        new ImmovableSprite(width, height, drawX, drawY, im, im.floor).draw(canvas);
                        break;
                    default:
                        img = im.wall;
                }
                new ImmovableSprite(width, height, drawX, drawY, im, img).draw(canvas);
                drawY += width / 9;
            }
            drawX += width / 9;
            drawY = getTerrainDrawData()[1];
        }
    }

    private void fillCanvas(Canvas canvas, int color) {
        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    }

    public int[] getTerrainDrawData() {
        /*
        [0] = start X pos
        [1] = start Y pos
        [2] = number of available blocks by Y axis
        */
        return new int[] {width / 18, (height / 2) % (width / 9), height / (width / 9)};
    }

    public void handleClick(int x, int y) {
        if (Math.abs(buttonDown.getCenterX() - x) <= width / 18 && Math.abs(buttonDown.getCenterY() - y) <= width / 18) {
            Log.v("LOG", "button was clicked");
            unit.move(0, 1);
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: кто минус поставил? я же сказал, если нужен код пишите в комментариях, я добавлю. От того, что вопрос слишком тупой, минусы не ставят

Comment: Должно работать. У вас CustomView? На чем рисуете?

Comment: DrawSurface extends View. Щас пришлю полный код класса

Comment: все @Style-7 можете смотреть на мой говнокод

Comment: вызывайте просто invalidate()

Comment: оно и так не работает я пробовал

Comment: оно работает, я так понял вы вызываете по клику в handleClick, Клик проходит в Log? у вас возможно ничего не двигается, посмотрите unit.move(0, 1); и кстати fillCanvas заменяет одна команда canvas.drawColor Поставьте Log в onDraw - сразу все поймете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался. Оказывается проблема была не в `invalidate()`, а в том, что я слепой и не заметил что у меня не работает функция `unit.move()`. Теперь она работает)

Comment: так я вам писал об этом

Comment: нет, вы писали про то, что нужно вместо invalidate() вызвать другую функцию. нормально все было с инвалидэйтом

Comment: Прочтите мой последний комментарий к вопросу

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй вместо **invalidate()** вызвать **requestLayout()** он должен будет обновить твой view и совет лучше не создавать в методе draw() или onDraw() новые объекты (так google советует), лучшее инициализировать в конструкторе или в блоке инициализаций

Comment: requestLayout() не нужно вызывать он предназначен для других целей

Comment: Насчет создавания объектов. У меня их много. Я задолбаюсь менять битмапы 100500 спрайтам в соответствии с ландшафтом. Поэтому вот

Comment: invalidate работает, а unit.move() не работает. спасибо я разобрался